# Is there a way to unzip '.gz' files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does anyone here know of a simple way to unzip hundreds of files with '.gz' extension?  I found code to do this for '.zip' files, but not for '.gz' files.  If possible, I'd like to get all these files unzipped, and have '.txt' extension added to the name of each.  If someone has code to do this, please share.  I am using Python 3.7.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty trivial one-liner in shell, and using `gunzip` is likely to be faster, particularly with xargs running multiple instances in parallel; are you looking specifically for a Python implementation?

Comment: ...for example, if you have 16 CPUs, and want to pass 8 files to each instance (bigger numbers for `-n` reduce overhead, but make parallelization worse at the end of the batch; whereas `-P` should roughly match up with the number of files you have CPU and I/O bandwidth to handle at a time): `find . -name '*.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 8 -P 16 sh -c 'for arg; do gunzip -c <"$arg" >"${arg%.gz}.txt"; done' _`

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python gunzip", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: Why was this put on hold?  It was pretty clear what I was asking for.  I don't see how the question is too broad.

Comment: Please don't post answers in the question post. We are not supposed to mix questions and answers as per SO rules. Instead, improve the question with the code you have tried before. Ask for reopen and then post your answer. This way it will be helpful/useful and your question will be valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import gzip
import shutil
with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'rb') as f_in:
    with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```